# Estimate $\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos\theta\right)}{\sin\theta}\right)^2$

Tags: strichartz-estimates

I need to show that:
$\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos\theta\right)}{\sin\theta}\right)^2\simeq \sin^3(\theta)$

I used Matlab, their graphs are very similar.
How to prove above estimate?

Comment: The left hand side should be $\mid \sin(\theta)\mid^3$.

Comment: They are [not even close](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(cos(pi*cos(theta)%2F2)%2Fsin(theta))%5E2%2F%7Csin%5E3(theta)%7C) to being almost equal.

Comment: From the graphs they appear to be approximately equal only in neighborhoods of multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. But they can differ in between by as much as $0.05$. The approximation is better at **odd** multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ut816vneht

Comment: The error is a third as big, around 0.017, for $|\sin(x)|^{2.63}$

Comment: Well, it's not difficult to prove $c\,\sin^2\theta\le\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos\theta\right)}{\sin\theta}\right)^2\le C\,\sin^2\theta$ with some constants $0<c<C$, and that's certainly in contradiction with the claim, but as long as OP can't be bothered to react to comments, I can't be bothered to write that up.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Can you suggest me more?

Comment: First of all, you should make precise what the symbol $\simeq$ in your question is supposed to mean (a formal definition). That symbol is used for isomorphy, usually, but that doesn't make sense, here.